# How Do I Remove Space From a Tweet Button?

Tags: css, twitter

I know how to integrate Tweet buttons into WordPress blog posts, but I am having difficulty removing the space it leaves underneath it (shown in red).

[image]

I have tried adding `margin: 0;` and `padding: 0;` to the `twitter-share-button` class so that it is vertically in line with the post information, but nothing happens. How can I fix that?

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.twitter-share-button {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>By admin | Published January 1, 20XX <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="j_kantner">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script></p>
```

Comment: Share your url please? Also sometime line-height also helps in situations like this.

Comment: I was using a localhost test blog.

Comment: Glad you got the solution already by Blaze! Good luck :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script is adding an `iframe` to your page. The only way I could solve this problem is to add a `vertical-align : bottom;` to the `iframe`.

Here is JSFiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/r9cn4oh5/).

Comment: Using `vertical-align : bottom;` for `.twitter-share-button` also worked, but thanks for the info!

Comment: I rechecked the code, what's interesting is that the class, `.twitter-share-button`, belongs to the `iframe`, just like the ID, `#twitter-widget-0`. I hadn't noticed that!

Answer (score 1):

You could add the CSS rule:

```
iframe {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.twitter-share-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
iframe {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<p>By admin | Published January 1, 20XX <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="j_kantner">Tweet</a>
  <script>
    ! function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
      if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }
    }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
  </script>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use alignment instead

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
.twitter-share-button {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<del>Try adjusting the `<p>` paragraph that the button is inside of.</del>

Sorry I reread your question.
Use negative margins and or padding.

```css
.twitter-share-button {
  margin: -10px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<p>By admin | Published January 1, 20XX <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="j_kantner">Tweet</a>
  <script>
    ! function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
      if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }
    }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
  </script>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addtion to the other answers, you can use a negative value on the margin.

```
.twitter-share-button {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```